# how to merge netCDF file into one?

Tags: r

I did like this, with merge twice,

## library(ncdf)

```
setwd("F:/R Practie/NCDF/precipitation")

p6 = open.ncdf("wrf_prec_8p5.2006.nc")

p7 = open.ncdf("wrf_prec_8p5.2007.nc")

p8 = open.ncdf("wrf_prec_8p5.2008.nc")

p9 = open.ncdf("wrf_prec_8p5.2009.nc")
```

I want to this file p6,p7,p8,p9 into one p

```
p= merge(p6,p7,p8,all=TRUE)

p=merge(p,p9,all=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this pretty easily with NCO [ncrcat](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncrcat)

To concatenate files along the record dimension (the unlimited dimension) do:

```
ncrcat wrf_prec_8p5.200[6789].nc  wrf_prec_8p5.2006-2009.nc
```

This command will concatenate all the files.

Comment: I can't make it run properly when the netCDF files (*.nc4 in my case) are of different time spans. The NCO manual is hard to digest for now...

Answer (score 1):

You can merge instead using CDO:

```
cdo mergetime wrf_prec_8p5.????.nc merged_file.nc
```

However, from experience I find that CDO struggles with the WRF grid and you may find the dimensions renamed x_1, y_1 etc.  If you were using the NCL built in functions to read the data variables and plot, this can be problematic, but as you seem to be using R, I expect this is not an issue for you.