# Merging many single .nc files into one multi-file netCDF using r?

Tags: r, merge, netcdf, rbind, cdo-climate

I am trying to merge many single .nc files into one multi-file netCDF. I need to merge monthly files from 1901-2006 for a few variables e.g. temp (filename is tmp_cru-ts-4.03-gridded_1.75w50.75n1.75w50.75n_19010116)

My skills are pretty basic in R but I've tried this so far:

```
filenames=list.files("tmp", pattern = '*.nc', full.names = TRUE)
ldf = lapply(filenames,open.nc)             #rnetcdf function
binded = rbind(ldf)
```

I'm not sure if this is right, or how to now write it to a .nc file?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096730/merge-netcdf-files-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101807/how-to-merge-netcdf-file-into-one ?

Comment: As you have tagged cdo-climate, try `cdo mergetime *.nc out.nc` or `cdo merge *.nc out.nc`, depending on what type of merge you are trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge netCDF files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096730/merge-netcdf-files-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

CDO can do this too

```
cdo cat in*.nc out.nc
```

or more robustly in this case where the files are for different times:

```
cdo mergetime in*.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 1):

NCO can do this with [ncrcat](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncrcat)

```
ncrcat in*.nc out.nc
```